# Is there a utility to display outlines of other resolutions on the screen?

Tags: display, resolution

I have a 17" MacBook Pro and occasionally need to design software that's optimized for smaller resolutions. Some of them I can work with by setting my display's resolution to the target system's, but there are a few resolutions (1400x900, for example) that aren't supported on my machine.

Is there a utility that will display a rectangle on the screen that will show me what the resolution would be for smaller displays?

BTW, I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion).

Thanks,

Chuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [xscope](http://xscopeapp.com/).
Its not expensive and it has "Screens" and "Frames" function which both should to be doing what you need.

Comment: Thanks very much. I actually already own that as part of a package I got from [MacHeist](http://www.macheist.com) a few months ago to get [Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/). Thanks for giving me a reason to check it out. It had been sitting in my software archive since the purchase.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an outline (or more) that shows a specific size, why not just create an image and use it as a wallpaper? Seems to me like the most app/memory/complicated-less solution.

Comment: As a fallback, that'll work, but I'd much prefer to have the outlines on top of everything else rather than underneath.

Comment: There's an app that records the screen while you're using it. It's called "Snapz Pro X". When recording, you have this nice feature of overlaying (on top of everything) an outline of the area being recorded (it's called "use movie guides"). You can even set its size and position. It's not meant for what you want, but it may be of help trying it. This is their site: http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/

Answer (score 0):

This was sort of answered on [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/247/is-there-a-standard-width-for-designing-web-page-mockups)

> Google has a nice development tool called [Browser Size](http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but while the Google utility has useful information, it certainly isn't as convenient as having the outline of lower resolutions on my screen would be, especially as I'm developing desktop applications, not web applications.